# Dynamically call the right most data from a range of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple excel sheet where weekly sales quantities are being recorded. Each week new data is added to the right of the week prior.

I have a summary sheet on a different tab of the same workbook - I am trying to have the summary sheet automatically update the weeks summary, once new data is added to the weekly sheet.

Is there a way to define a range of cells which extend right into future date ranges, and have the most recently added data be what is pulled into the summary?

Comment: When you say 'to the right', I suppose you mean columns? This formula will get the value of last non-empty column of row 1, in columns A to Z (you can have blanks in between): =LOOKUP(2;1/(A1:Z1<>"");A1:Z1)

Comment: Until a new week has arrived, nothing is entered in the next column? Is it completely empty? There are people who pre-mark the head of the table with the dates of future reports in 7-day increments. Don't you do that? The hardest part of your task is to find the last completed column in the table. Therefore, we need to know whether to take into account the entire column when searching or starting from the second row (since the date of the future report is already in the first row). The rest of the work is easily done by the OFFSET() function.

Answer (score 0):

`ZivkoK`'s comment has the traditional, and wonderfully short, way of doing it. Highly recommended.

Its downside is it is not immediately obvious to many just how it is doing its work, which can lead to difficulties justifying the technique to bosses. But other than that, simple, and no huge footprint.

A different way, with a big footprint, so not winning "formula golf" any time soon, uses `FILTERXML()`:

```
=FILTERXML("<Group><Element>"&TEXTJOIN("</Element><Element>",TRUE,A11:AF11)&"</Element></Group>","/Group/Element[last()]")
```

An advantage though is that one can return not only the last element, but any other by position/index/number. The 4th, perhaps, or the 17th. But since the last one can be directly addressed without knowing how many total elements the array has, it is easily accessible.

Basically, the `TEXTJOIN()` takes the row's cells and makes a string of them. In this case, columns A through AF. The first two parameters are the separator (not a simple comma here, but rather the XML tags you will need), and whether to include empty cells or not ("not" in this case). Since specifying "FALSE" for the latter, you can specify the entire set of columns that could ever be used and the function ignores any not actually/yet being used.

Then the leading and lagging tags are joined to its output to make a string `FILTERXML()` can recognize as XML and parse using the "XML path" you specify. (The tags used can be anything, but I use the verbose "Group" and "Element" tags rather than the "a" and "b" tags people often use as I feel that the interim results the formula provides could maybe be useful to someone trying to follow the work. Likely never be needed, but there it is.)

Finally, adding the `[last()]` to the "XML path" tells `FILTERXML()` to return just the last element of the original `TEXTJOIN()` array (which never included the empty cell values).

(You are building a string for `FILTERXML()` which includes that "[last()]" and you can use string building techniques to specify other elements instead. So, say you want to subtract the last element from the next-to-last element. You could build the element part of that string using `COUNT/COUNTA` and subtracting 1. Now you have both and can march onward. This is something the `LOOKUP()` approach cannot easily do.)